# Send data in continuous intervals via Kalman filter in an event based system

Tags: c++, queue, cycle, kalman-filter

I have a filter based program, where one filter receives data every ~200ms. When a new sample is received a corresponding event is fired. I process the data via a Kalman Filter. Afterwards I send the processed data to the next filter.
Now I want to generate data on the output side (Kalman filtered input data) with a shorter cycle (~30ms). My question is, what is a good way to achieve this.

My idea is to have a seperate thread with a cycle timer (30ms). When a new sample is received it is added to a queue. At every timer event I check if there are samples in the queue. If so, I use this value as the measurement input for the Kalman filter. If not, I use the prediction ability of the Kalman using the cycle time.

Is this the way to go, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and no!  Can you use the first Kalman filter to propagate between the 30 ms measurement intervals of the second Kalman filter?  Yes - you can.  If your last measurement into the first filter was at 400 ms, then your best estimate of the output of the first filter 30 ms later comes from propagating that forward to 430 ms.  If the state propagation is linear you use the same transition matrix (usually denoted Phi) with the 30 ms delta-time to propagate the state.

The problem comes in the second filter.  If it is assuming it's getting measurements with white Gaussian noise as most filter implementations do, then the output from the 430 ms will be a badly modeled measurement, as the errors in the measurement at 430 ms will be highly correlated with the errors in the measurement at 400 ms.  In both cases the last measurement processed in the first filter was the 400 ms measurement.

There are several possible methods of treating time-correlated measurement noise in the second filter.  They include adding one or more states to the second filter to track the correlated portion of the measurement noise, and subtracting this estimate of the correlated noise from the input from the first filter.  This "pre-whitens" the measurement sequence into the second filter.